# Magento 1 show error on checkout if input is longer than

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout, customer-address

Our payment service provider only allow certain input lengths for some fields.

In this case I want to show a inputfield error in the checkout, when the input of the street name is longer than 35 characters for example.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the class `validate-length maximum-length-35` in every template where there is an input for the street.

For example, in `app/design/frontend/<your-package>/<your-theme>/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`, replace :

```
class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>"
```

by

```
class="input-text validate-length maximum-length-35 <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>"
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! Do you also know how to translate the given error message? I already change the sentince inside the Mage_Core.csv file. But that does not translate the message.

Comment: You shouldn't edit a core file, even if it's a `csv` file ;). By the way, it's weird that it's not translated with your change...(did you flush the cache, etc)  To translate `Text length does not satisfy specified text range.`, I would use a `translate.csv` file in `app/design/frontend/<your-theme>/default/locale/<your-locale>/translate.csv`.